# req.body esta vindo vazio ao chamar api no postman e na aplicação

Tags: node.js, api, http-request, https

estoutentando consumir uma api em nodejs porem não consigo passar os parametros o req.body esta ficando vazio e não consigo identificar o problema

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var core_use = require('cors');
var sql = require("mssql");
```

app.use(core_use());
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

var retorno = {
    method: '',
    uri: '',
    response: []
};

app.get('/consultarCartaoSus', function (req, res) {
    sql.connect(config, function (err) {
        var request = new sql.Request();
        console.log(req.body);
        // query to the database and get the records ''
        request.query('select * from clientes ', function (err, response) {
            if (err) {
                sql.close();
                console.log(err);
            };
            retorno.method = 'GET';
            retorno.uri = 'consultarCartaoSus';
            retorno.response = response.recordsets;

`res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        res.json(retorno);
        sql.close();
    });

});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como você está utilizando o método GET para esta rota é notável você utilizar os parâmetros que deseja utilizar, para assim, recupera-los na sua aplicação. Observe um exemplo de como recuperar informações utilizando o app.get do [express](http://expressjs.com/pt-br/api.html):

```
app.get('/api-teste/:parametro1', (req, res) => {
    var parametro1 = req.params.parametro1;
});
```